# Can someone diagnose this CSS issue?

Tags: html, css

Hey there, can someone help diagnose this CSS issue, as I have no idea what the beep is going on;

Here's my CSS:

```
#navigation {
display: inline;
}

.download {
width: 10px;
height: 40px;
}

.steps {
width: 90px;
height: 40px;
}
```

And here's my HTML:

```
<div id="navigation">
<div class="download"></div>
<div class="steps"></div>
</div>
```

For some reason, even though display:inline; is being used, the classes still drop below one another.

And before someone comments on why I'm not using a unordered list to create my navigation, this is meant to be quickie job with a pretty low pay, so the best form isn't what I'm going for. That said, I've been trying to diagnose this issue for over half an hour, and I'm stumped. I've clearly made an obvious mistake, I just can't pick up on it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :).

Comment: "this is meant to be quickie job with a pretty low pay" - you seem to know that it would be better to use an unordered list; wouldn't that have been faster, too, since you know about it already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just float all of your divs left and achieve the same result.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Worked perfectly. I was under the impression that all HTML elements were floated left by default, or at least, should be, as I'm pretty sure that I've done similar stuff before with no issue, hence why I was so puzzled now?

Comment: It's all good, floats can be tricky if you don't work with them alot. Please remember to accept this as your answer if you feel it was the best fit

Answer (score 3):

The parent `div` is inline, not the children. You haven't done anything with the children, they're still `block`. Your problem will likely be solved if you make the children `inline-block` though, with:

```
.download, .steps {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Or you can float them:

```
.download, .steps {
    float: left;
}

#navigation {
    overflow: hidden;
    zoom: 1; /* if you care for the anti-browser */
}
```

All this is if you do care for them to keep the width and height you specified, while keeping them next to each other.

Comment: Still drops down unfortunately. I have no idea what the hell is going on.

Comment: Brilliant, floating worked. As I mentioned in another comment, I was under the impression that HTML elements were floated left by default, indeed perhaps I was wrong, but I'm using a different css-reset stylesheet now, which might explain why it was so puzzling, as I'm pretty sure I've done similar stuff before with no issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe divs inherit their parents display property by default, and divs are block.  So you would have to set both .download and .steps to also be display:inline

You could also create a selector like:

```
#navigation div { display:inline; }
```

More than likely, you want #navigation to be block anyways, since you will probably want the navigation container to be block.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a style on the div's in the #navigation div...

```
#navigation, #navigation > div {
display: inline;
}
```